# Lucene search for database

Tags: java

Using Lucene, i am able to search through a single table. It is giving me results even if I do Search By Keyword. But the same when I am applying on 2 tables. No results are getting found. I made 2 Indexer objects for searching 2 different tables. I am new to Lucene Kindly help out.

Comment: are you using Lucene in standalone mode where you index the data into lucene index files and search them or are you using some ORM integrated with lucene?

Comment: Hi Abdul,Thanks for the response,I am currently using Hibernate search 3.4 for searching on my database,taking only 1 table for now..After importing bundles of jar files i m getting exception for "ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.event.PostCollectionRecreateEventListener" Kindly tell me how to sort it out?